# Partner Account ID-Lead Object

Tags: formula, salesforce-id, formula-field

There is Partner Account field on lead object. Salesforce help says, Description:ID of the partner account for the partner user that owns this lead. Available only if Partner Relationship Management is enabled OR Communities is enabled and you have partner portal licenses.

Although field says lookup,it looks like will be prepopulated when a partner user creates a lead.

Is there any way to get content(ID of account) of this field.

When i try Lead.PartnerAccountID  it says field doesnt exist

Does anyone have a clue?.It would be really good to get hold of this field

Answer (score 2):

I have done various research and experiments on this field on the Lead object and below what I understand:

- It's possible to retrieve the value of the field only through SOQL
- It cannot be used in a formula field
- It's automatically filled with the value of the lead owner's partner account and in this case it's read only
- It can be edited manually if the "**Allow editing of the Partner Account field on opportunities and leads**" option is selected in SETUP-> COMMUNITIES SETTINGS and in this case it's not automatically filled in by SFDC
- To activate it you need to configure Communities and have an active partner licenses in the ORG